# Changing LayoutParams programmatically has no effect in Android. Why?

Tags: android, layout

I have a custom view, derived from `Button`, which I want to position at runtime, relative to another view. Because I don't know that other view's position yet when my view is being inflated (because layouting hasn't started), I leverage the `onSizeChanged` handler to set my view's position relative to the other view.

In `onSizeChanged`:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(this.getMeasuredWidth(), this.getMeasuredHeight());
lp.leftMargin = x;
lp.topMargin = y;
this.setLayoutParams(lp);

forceLayout();
```

That, however, has no effect. How come?

Comment: Observation: offsetTopAndBottom() and offsetLeftAndRight() do the job. Must be something about these method which works differently than just setting new LayoutParams (haven't yet looked at the source).

Answer (score 4):

Some things to consider:

1. Are you sure this code is being executed?
2. Have you examined the UI in `hierarchyviewer` to see if the margins are being set but they are simply not having the visual effect you expect?
3. Are you sure this isn't better handled just via a `RelativeLayout`?
4. Have you tried modifying the existing `LayoutParams` rather than replacing it?

Comment: Hi Mark. 1,2: yes; 3: Can't do, I merge with the parent FrameLayout; 4: No, I'll give that a try.